# How to access the type arguments of typing.Generic?

Tags: python, generics

The [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module provides a base class for generic type hints: The [`typing.Generic`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) class.

Subclasses of `Generic` accept type arguments in square brackets, for example:

```
list_of_ints = typing.List[int]
str_to_bool_dict = typing.Dict[str, bool]
```

---

My question is, how can I access these type arguments?

That is, given `str_to_bool_dict` as input, how can I get `str` and `bool` as output?

Basically I'm looking for a function such that

```
>>> magic_function(str_to_bool_dict)
(<class 'str'>, <class 'bool'>)
```

Comment: Note that the same methods (`.__args__` ([almost undocumented](https://bugs.python.org/issue42195#msg380048)), [`typing.get_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args)) work with other things in `typing` module too (`_GenericAlias`, `_SpecialForm` -- which contains `Any`, `NoReturn`, `ClassVar`, `Union`, `Optional`). Also `get_args(Optional[str])` returns the same thing as `get_args(Union[str, NoneType])`.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

### Python >= 3.8

As of Python3.8 there is [`typing.get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args):

```
print( get_args( List[int] ) ) # (<class 'int'>,)
```

[PEP-560](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0560/) also provides `__orig_bases__[n]`, which allows us the arguments of the *n*th generic base:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, get_args

T = TypeVar( "T" )

class Base( Generic[T] ):
    pass

class Derived( Base[int] ):
    pass

print( get_args( Derived.__orig_bases__[0] ) ) # (<class 'int'>,)
```

---

### Python >= 3.6

As of Python 3.6. there is a public `__args__` and (`__parameters__`) field.
For instance:

```
print( typing.List[int].__args__ )
```

This contains the generic parameters (i.e. `int`), whilst `__parameters__` contains the generic itself (i.e. `~T`).

---

### Python < 3.6

Use [typing_inspect.getargs](https://github.com/ilevkivskyi/typing_inspect)

---

### Some considerations

`typing` follows [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Both PEP8 and `typing` are coauthored by Guido van Rossum. A double leading and trailing underscore is defined in  as: *"“magic” objects or attributes that live in **user-controlled namespaces**"*.

The dunders are also commented in-line; from the official repository for [typing](https://github.com/python/typing) we
can see:

- *"`__args__` is a tuple of all arguments used in subscripting, e.g., `Dict[T, int].__args__ == (T, int)`".*

However, the [authors also note](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/480):

- *"The typing module has provisional status, so it is not covered by the high standards of backward compatibility (although we try to keep it as much as possible), this is especially true for (yet undocumented) dunder attributes like `__union_params__`. If you want to work with typing types in runtime context, then you may be interested in the `typing_inspect` project (part of which may end up in typing later)."*

I general, whatever you do with `typing` will need to be kept up-to-date for the time being. If you need forward compatible changes, I'd recommend writing your own annotation classes.

Comment: How do you know that this is public? If you have any sources, please cite them.

Comment: "How do you know that this is public " - because `__xxx__` is always public and, unlike `_xxx` and `__xxx` has never suggested otherwise. I presume you mean "How do you know that this is documented". I've updated my answer with documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to access the generic type if the class is only generic in the type stub (.pyi) file and not the actual runtime class?

Comment: From the base class I was able to retrieve the type using `T: Type[Any]= get_args(self.__orig_bases__[0])[0]`, where `T` in the actual type. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

As far as I know, there is no happy answer here.

What comes to mind is the `__args__` undocumented attribute which stores this information:

```
list_of_ints.__args__
>>>(<class 'int'>,)

str_to_bool_dict.__args__
>>>(<class 'str'>, <class 'bool'>)
```

but there is no mention of it in the documentation of the `typing` module.

It is worth noting that it was [very close to be mentioned](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/335) in the documentation though:

> Probably we should also discuss whether we need to document all keyword arguments for `GenericMeta.__new__`. There are `tvars`, `args`, `origin`, `extra`, and `orig_bases`. I think we could say something about first three (they correspond to `__parameters__`, `__args__`, and `__origin__` and these are used by most things in typing).

But [it did not quite make it](https://github.com/python/typing/pull/340):

> I added `GenericMeta` to `__all__` and added docstrings to `GenericMeta` and `GenericMeta.__new__` following the discussion in the issue.
>   I decided not to describe `__origin__` and friends in docstrings. Instead, I just added a comment at the place where they are first used.

From there, you still have three non-mutually exclusive options:

- wait for the `typing` module to reach full maturity and hope these features will be documented soon
- join the [Python ideas mailing list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-ideas) and see if enough support can be gathered to make these internals public / part of the API
- work in the meantime with the undocumented internals, making a gamble that there won't be changes to these or that the changes will be minor.

Note that the third point can hardly be avoided as even the [API can be subject to changes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html):

> The typing module has been included in the standard library on a provisional basis. New features might be added and **API may change even between minor releases if deemed necessary by the core developers**.

Comment: I'd suggest rephrasing your answer to put more focus on "The `__args__` attribute does what you want". At the moment your answer is talking mostly about the documentation and discussion of all these internal attributes, and you only mention `__args__` in passing. Even just a single line of code showing the output of `str_to_bool_dict.__args__` would go a long way in making your answer better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this inner method will do the trick

```
typing.List[int]._subs_tree()
```

which returns the tuple:

```
(typing.List, <class 'int'>)
```

But this a private API, probably there is a better answer.

Comment: Indeed, it's unclear if that's an implementation detail or not. Relying on this to work seems a little risky.

Comment: Totally agree, I dig up this just now and the internals are very complex (there is some recursion happening in _subs_tree() for reaching to this result).

Comment: Should point out that the `typing` module is still under active (and code-breaking) development. If you want this feature to stick around, I'd recommend submitting a use case rather than not using it: https://github.com/python/typing/issues .

Answer (score 4):

The question asks specifically about `typing.Generic`, but it turns out that (at least in earlier versions of the `typing` module) not all subscriptable types are subclasses of `Generic`. In newer versions, all subscriptable types store their arguments in the `__args__` attribute:

```
>>> List[int].__args__
(<class 'int'>,)
>>> Tuple[int, str].__args__
(<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>)
```

In python 3.5, however, some classes like `typing.Tuple`, `typing.Union` and `typing.Callable` stored them in different attributes like `__tuple_params__`, `__union_params__` or generally in `__parameters__`. For completeness's sake, here's a function that can extract the type arguments from any subscriptable type in any python version:

```
import typing


if hasattr(typing, '_GenericAlias'):
    # python 3.7
    def _get_base_generic(cls):
        # subclasses of Generic will have their _name set to None, but
        # their __origin__ will point to the base generic
        if cls._name is None:
            return cls.__origin__
        else:
            return getattr(typing, cls._name)
else:
    # python <3.7
    def _get_base_generic(cls):
        try:
            return cls.__origin__
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        name = type(cls).__name__
        if not name.endswith('Meta'):
            raise NotImplementedError("Cannot determine base of {}".format(cls))

        name = name[:-4]
        try:
            return getattr(typing, name)
        except AttributeError:
            raise NotImplementedError("Cannot determine base of {}".format(cls))


if hasattr(typing.List, '__args__'):
    # python 3.6+
    def _get_subtypes(cls):
        subtypes = cls.__args__

        if _get_base_generic(cls) is typing.Callable:
            if len(subtypes) != 2 or subtypes[0] is not ...:
                subtypes = (subtypes[:-1], subtypes[-1])

        return subtypes
else:
    # python 3.5
    def _get_subtypes(cls):
        if isinstance(cls, typing.CallableMeta):
            if cls.__args__ is None:
                return ()

            return cls.__args__, cls.__result__

        for name in ['__parameters__', '__union_params__', '__tuple_params__']:
            try:
                subtypes = getattr(cls, name)
                break
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("Cannot extract subtypes from {}".format(cls))

        subtypes = [typ for typ in subtypes if not isinstance(typ, typing.TypeVar)]
        return subtypes


def get_subtypes(cls):
    """
    Given a qualified generic (like List[int] or Tuple[str, bool]) as input, return
    a tuple of all the classes listed inside the square brackets.
    """
    return _get_subtypes(cls)
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> get_subtypes(List[int])
(<class 'int'>,)
>>> get_subtypes(Tuple[str, bool])
(<class 'str'>, <class 'bool'>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.__args__` on your constructs. So the magic function you need is something like --

```
get_type_args = lambda genrc_type: getattr(genrc_type, '__args__')
```

---

> My question is, how can I access these type arguments?

In situations like these -- how do I access ...

Use Python's powerful introspection features.

Even as a non-pro programmer I know I am trying to inspect stuff and `dir` is a function which is like IDE in terminal. So after

```
>>> import typing
>>> str_to_bool_dict = typing.Dict[str, bool]
```

I want to see if there's anything that does the magic you want so

```
>>> methods = dir(str_to_bool_dict)
>>> methods
['__abstractmethods__', '__args__', .....]
```

I see too much info, to see if I am correct I verify

```
>>> len(methods)
53
>>> len(dir(dict))
39
```

Now let us find the methods which were designed specifically for generic types

```
>>> set(methods).difference(set(dir(dict)))
{'__slots__', '__parameters__', '_abc_negative_cache_version', '__extra__',
'_abc_cache', '__args__', '_abc_negative_cache', '__origin__',
'__abstractmethods__', '__module__', '__next_in_mro__', '_abc_registry',
'__dict__', '__weakref__'}
```

among these, `__parameters__`, `__extra__`, `__args__` and `__origin__` sound helpful. `__extra__` and `__origin__` won't work without self so we are left with `__parameters__` and `__args__`.

```
>>> str_to_bool_dict.__args__
(<class 'str'>, <class 'bool'>)
```

Hence the answer.

---

Introspection allows `py.test`'s `assert` statements to make JUnit derived testing frameworks look obsolete. Even languages like JavaScript / Elm / Clojure don't have a straight-forward thingy like `dir` of Python. Python's naming convention allows you to discover the language without actually reading (grokking in some cases such as these) the documentations.

So hunt using introspection and read documentation/mailing-lists to confirm your findings.

P.S. To OP -- this method also answers your question [What's the correct way to check if an object is a typing.Generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171189/) use discovery if you can't commit to mailing list or are a busy developer - that's the way to do it in python.

Comment: I'm aware I can fire up an interactive session and dissect the internals of the typing module. The point of the question is that *I don't want to do that*. I specifically asked what the *official, documented* solution is.

Comment: Earlier answers already showed about `__args__` attribute. This answer just seems to add unnecessary waffle on top of that.