# extracting data from typing types

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, type-hinting, instanceof

I am having some issues working with the `typing` types in Python for any more than type hinting:

```py
>>> from typing import List
>>> string_list = ['nobody', 'expects', 'the', 'spanish', 'inqusition']
>>> string_list_class = List[str]
```

Now I would like to

1. Check if `string_list` conforms to `string_list_class`.
2. Check if `string_list_class` is a list.
3. If so, check the class, that `string_list_class` is a list of.

I find myself unable to achieve any of those:

```py
>>> isinstance(string_list, string_list_class)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 708, in __instancecheck__
    return self.__subclasscheck__(type(obj))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 716, in __subclasscheck__
    raise TypeError("Subscripted generics cannot be used with"
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks

>>> issubclass(string_list_class, List)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 716, in __subclasscheck__
    raise TypeError("Subscripted generics cannot be used with"
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) also is not really helpful with that. Also the API does not seem to be intended to be used that way, **however, I need to use that functionality**.

### Bodging around

A way I found to answer 2. is, that

```py
>>> type(string_list_class)
<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>
```

Tough I have no access to `_GenericAlias` I can build it myself:

```py
>>> _GenericAlias = type(List[str])
>>> isinstance(string_list_class, _GenericAlias)
True
```

However that does not seem like a good solution at all and it also yields `True` for other classes like `Collection`.

For 1. and 3. I could imagine hacking something together with `repr(type(string_list))` and `repr(string_list_class)` and somehow comparing that string to something, but that also is not a good solution.

**But there must be a better way to do this**

Comment: I get point 1, but what's the purpose of point 2? If `string_list` conforms to `string_list_class`, then you already know that it's a list. And I have no idea what point 3 is supposed to mean.

Comment: I want to check if `string_list_class` is a List type in general. It might be a list of `str`, `int`, `MyObject` or something else. This is unrelated to 1. With 3 I want to extract `MyObject` from `List[MyObject]`.

Comment: Ok, I see. But... I'm not sure if it's a good idea to ask 3 mostly unrelated questions at the same time...

Comment: I agree, but they are not entirely unrelated IMHO, and answers to one or two of those questions could answer the others. I was unable to find a solution, but if there is one, the same source probably also could answer the other questions.

Comment: For point 3, see [How to access the type arguments of typing.Generic?](//stackoverflow.com/q/48572831). And [What's the correct way to check if an object is a typing.Generic?](//stackoverflow.com/q/49171189) might help with point 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the type arguments of typing.Generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572831/how-to-access-the-type-arguments-of-typing-generic)

Comment: yes, however a very similar answer is has also been posted in response to this question so I accepted that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Checking if a variable conforms to a typing object

To check if `string_list` conforms to `string_list_class`, you can use the [typeguard](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard) type checking library.

```py
from typeguard import check_type

try:
    check_type('string_list', string_list, string_list_class)
    print("string_list conforms to string_list_class")
except TypeError:
    print("string_list does not conform to string_list_class")
```

### Checking the generic type of a typing object

To check if `string_list_class` is a list type, you can use the [typing_inspect](https://github.com/ilevkivskyi/typing_inspect) library:

```py
from typing_inspect import get_origin
from typing import List

get_origin(List[str]) # -> List
```

You could also use the private `__origin__` field, but there is no stability guarantee for it.

```py
List[str].__origin__ # -> list
```

### Checking the type argument of a typing object

To check the class, that `string_list_class` is a list of, you can use the [typing_inspect](https://github.com/ilevkivskyi/typing_inspect) library again.

```py
from typing_inspect import get_parameters
from typing import List

assert get_parameters(List[str])[0] == str
```

As before, there is also a private field you can use if you like to take risks

```py
List[str].__args__[0] # -> str
```

Comment: Worth noting that a lot of the functionality in typing_inspect doesn't work in python 3.9.  Unfortunately it seems that doing runtime checks for generic types can be a bit unreliable

Comment: See https://github.com/ilevkivskyi/typing_inspect/issues/65