# How are `[]` in `typing` module classes implemented?

Tags: python

With the `typing` module you can write

```
from typing import Dict
my_type: Dict[str, int]
```

where `Dict` is a class. My question is: *what are* the brackets following the class name. Which syntactic aspect of python allows that syntax? How could I do something similar in my own classes?

Comment: By cleverly implementing `__getitem__` :)

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: they can be seen as two aspects of the same question in fact. If (1) is answered, (2) probably follows.

Comment: @timgeb: thanks. I suspected so, but haven't seen `__getitem__` with `@classmethod`

Comment: Nope, they're two separate questions. Question #2 is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48572831/1222951).

Comment: @Aran-Fey: fine then, I'm editing

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to `@timgeb` for pointing me to the right direction. Turns out that it does use `__getitem__`. However, since `__getitem__` refers to an *instance*, you must define it in something that the current class is an instance of. So, you have to use a metaclass. Eg

```
class Root(type):
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        print(f'arguments: {i}')


class MyDict(metaclass=Root):
    pass
```

Now, with

```
MyDict[list, str]
```

you get

```
arguments: (<class 'list'>, <class 'str'>)
```

Comment: Good answer, you spelled out what I described with a lot of handwaving in my (now deleted) other comment. The "since `__getitem__` refers to an instance" could be more accurately worded as "special methods are looked up on the type of an object" (with classes being objects too, and having the type `type` by default) - and more accurately by referring to the relevant part of the [data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup). Using `[]` is an *implicit* use of `__getitem__`.

Comment: Slight quibble: `arguments` is misleading. There is exactly one argument (apart from self) to `__getitem__`, it just happens that in this case you are passing it a tuple.That does matter because `MyDict[int]` will not get a tuple, `MyDict[int, str]` will get a tuple.