# How to check TypeVar's Type at runtime

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, static-typing

I have a generic class `Graph[Generic[T], object]`.
My question, is there any function which returns type passed as generic to the class `Graph`

```py
>>> g = Graph[int]()
>>> magic_func(g)
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: See also: [**Generic\[T\] base class - how to get type of T from within instance?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57706180/1164465)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve this which works from Python 3.6+ (tested it in 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class Graph(Generic[T], object):
    def get_generic_type(self):
        print(self.__orig_class__.__args__[0])


if __name__=='__main__':
    g_int = Graph[int]()
    g_str = Graph[str]()

    g_int.get_generic_type()
    g_str.get_generic_type()
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```

If you want to get the type inside `__new__` or `__init__` things get a little bit tricky, see the following post for more info: [Generic[T] base class - how to get type of T from within instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706180/generict-base-class-how-to-get-type-of-t-from-within-instance)

**Edit**

The library pytypes seems to provide a method that allow to get `__orig_class__` even from `__init__`, check the method `get_orig_class` available here: https://github.com/Stewori/pytypes/blob/master/pytypes/type_util.py