# How to use isinstance on a generic type in Python

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to check whether an argument is an instance of the generic type specified in the class declaration. However Python does not seem to allow this.

```py
T = TypeVar('T')
class MyTypeChecker(Generic[T]):
    def is_right_type(self, x: Any):
        return isinstance(x, T)
```

This gives the error `'T' is a type variable and only valid in type context`.

Comment: Types hints **are not types**. There is no such thing as a "generic type* in the sense of *actual python types*. And furthermore, as is stated in the error message, `T` is a *type variable*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `__orig_class__` attribute, but keep in mind that this is an implementation detail, in more detail in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706180/generict-base-class-how-to-get-type-of-t-from-within-instance/60984681#60984681).

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Any
T = TypeVar('T')


class MyTypeChecker(Generic[T]):
    def is_right_type(self, x: Any):
        return isinstance(x, self.__orig_class__.__args__[0])  # type: ignore


a = MyTypeChecker[int]()
b = MyTypeChecker[str]()

print(a.is_right_type(1))  # True
print(b.is_right_type(1))  # False
print(a.is_right_type('str'))  # False
print(b.is_right_type('str'))  # True
```