# Get generic substituted type

Tags: python, generics, typing, pydantic

I have such class:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel

T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseModel)

class A(Generic[T]):
    def some_method(self) -> T:
        ... # some data processing
        return T.from_orm(some_data_model)

# in tests package:
class Model(BaseModel): ...
A[Model].some_method()
assert Model.from_orm.called_once
```

But it doesn't work because `T` is **not** a real type(`BaseModel`) but only `TypeVar` that bounds to `BaseModel`.

So the question is: how can I get the **real**(substituted) type `T`?

Important notes:

> it doesn't matter for me what the type the method is(classmethod, method of object instance or staticmethod)

> my python version is 3.8

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50101934/8506506) answer doesn't helped me:

I tried this:

```py
from typing import ..., get_args
#   ...
    def some_method(self) -> T:
        ...
        return get_args(type(self))[0].from_orm(some_data_model)
```

This:

```py
from typing import ..., get_args
#   ...
    @classmethod
    def some_method(cls) -> T:
        ...
        return get_args(cls)[0].from_orm(some_data_model)
```

And this:

```py
from typing import ..., get_args
#   ...
    @classmethod
    def some_method(cls) -> T:
        ...
        return get_args(A)[0].from_orm(some_data_model)
```

And I call it in a such way(if it is class/static method):

```py
A[Model].some_method()
```

And if it is instance method:

```py
A[Model]().some_method()
```

And all of it(without calling `from_orm` and getting index 0) just returns empty tuple and the whole method ends with `IndexError`(which is totally right).

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927793/how-to-use-isinstance-on-a-generic-type-in-python/

Comment: @alex_noname oh, I wasn't able to find the answer with `__orig_class__`. thank you! I'm going to write the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments @alex_noname posted a link to another such question.

In my case the answer was to use the `__orig_class__` attribute of the `self` object:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, get_args
from pydantic import BaseModel

T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseModel)

class A(Generic[T]):
    def some_method(self) -> T:
        ... # some data processing
        return get_args(self.__orig_class__)[0].from_orm(some_data_model)
```

For more information please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60984681/8506506)