# getting the type value of an instantiated class

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the value of an instantiated generic type at runtime? As in the following code:

```
T = TypeVar("T")
class Foo(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"instantiated type: {???}")  

o1 = Foo[int]() # this should print int
o2 = Foo[bool]() # this should print bool
```

What should I put in the `???` to print the appropriate values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706180/generict-base-class-how-to-get-type-of-t-from-within-instance