# Getting the generic arguments of a subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, types, python-typing

I have a generic base class and I want to be able to inspect the provided type for it. My approach was using [`typing.get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) which works like so:

```py
from typing import Generic, Tuple, TypeVarTuple, get_args

T = TypeVarTuple("T")


class Base(Generic[*T]):
    values: Tuple[*T]


Example = Base[int, str]
print(get_args(Example)) # (<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>)
```

But when I'm inheriting the class, I'm getting an empty list of parameters like so:

```py
class Example2(Base[int, str]):
    pass


print(get_args(Example2)) # ()
```

What I actually need is to know what types are expected for the `values` property. I might have the wrong approach but I've also tried to use [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) which seems to just return `Tuple[*T]` as the type.

So how can I get the typed parameters?

Edit: I need to know the types of the *class*, not the object.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71720366/8091093

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `get_args` with `__orig_bases__`:

```py
print(get_args(Example2.__orig_bases__[0]))  # prints "(<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>)"
```

For convenience, you can store the generic type parameters in the `__init_subclass__` hook:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVarTuple, get_args

T = TypeVarTuple("T")


class Base(Generic[*T]):
    values: tuple[*T]
    type_T: tuple[type, ...]

    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
        cls.type_T = get_args(cls.__orig_bases__[0])  # type: ignore


class Example2(Base[int, str]):
    pass


print(Example2.type_T)  # prints "(<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>)"
```

Comment: which python version is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the python function

```
help(package.class)
```

to retrieve documentation on the class. This doesn't directly return all possible arguments but all possible arguments should be listed in the return.

This will give you the arguments available, unless it a requirement to retrieve just the arguments to plug in to something else, in which case this may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah I need to get it in a proper data structure, but thanks