# How do I quiet mypy when testing inheritence from a generic?

Tags: python, generics, types

The following MWE constructs a mapping between the typevars used in a generic class and their declared values on an instance:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, get_args

T = TypeVar("T")


class Derived(Generic[T]):
    def method(self, val: T) -> T:
        return val


d = Derived[int]()


def get_generic_types_mapping(obj: object) -> dict[type, type]:
    if isinstance(obj, Generic):
        generic_base = next(
            origin
            for origin in obj.__orig_bases__
            if hasattr(origin, "__origin__") and origin.__origin__ is Generic
        )
        return {
            generic: decorated
            for generic, decorated in zip(
                get_args(generic_base), get_args(obj.__orig_class__)
            )
        }
    else:
        return {}


assert get_generic_types_mapping(d) == {T: int}
assert get_generic_types_mapping(object()) == {}
```

This code works fine, but mypy (and pyright) doesn't (don't) like it:

```bash
$ mypy t.py
t.py:15: error: Argument 2 to "isinstance" has incompatible type "<typing special form>"; expected "_ClassInfo"  [arg-type]
t.py:18: error: "object" has no attribute "__orig_bases__"  [attr-defined]
t.py:24: error: "object" has no attribute "__orig_class__"; maybe "__class__"?  [attr-defined]
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

This makes sense, as `Generic` objects really *don't* have an `__orig_bases__`:

```py
from typing import Generic

assert not hasattr(Generic(), "__orig_bases__")
```

How do I tell mypy that `obj` does have `__orig_bases__`?  [What do I read to understand where it comes from?]  Should I be using something other than `isinstance`?

(I thought of just `if hasattr(obj, "__orig_bases__")`, but this doesn't remove the error on `__orig_class__`, and I actually want to raise an error if a generic *doesn't* have defined types.  I could just check for both, but I feel like I'm missing something conceptually.)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that mypy is quite right here.  `GenericAlias.__orig_class__` is set by CPython's `typing` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e5dfcc2b6e1c8450e47acbc6e7d3fd3380ef0f03/Objects/genericaliasobject.c#L592), but the operation is fallible: it fails (for instance, if the target class uses `__slots__`), then the attribute is not available.

So the correct thing to do, unfortunately, is to check for the two attributes and handle the other cases.  Since I have access to the call signature on any classes I care about (either via `__orig_class__` or via explicit passing) I can just set them on a custom private attribute and use that instead.

For more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60984681/15452601) and source linked above.