# How to resolve a generic type at runtime

Tags: python, generics, sqlalchemy, python-typing

Below is the working code for a generic repository structure I’m fleshing out. The subclass, which is designed to work with SQLAlchemy, needs to know the type of `TEntity`, and this is where I’ve hit a wall. It seems there should be a way to resolve the type at runtime so I don’t have to explicitly set it in the subclass the way I’m doing it now. But if I don’t, the runtime thinks the type is `TypeVar(~TEntity)` when needed for get_by_id.

How can I do have `TEntity` fully resolved in a more elegant way?

```
from src.core.domain.securities.security import Security
from src.external.sql_alchemy_repository import SqlAlchemyRepository


class SecurityRepository(SqlAlchemyRepository[Security]):

    def __init__(self, session):
        super().__init__(session)
        self._entity_type = Security

import uuid

from src.core.domain.seedwork.repository import AbstractRepository, TEntity


class SqlAlchemyRepository(AbstractRepository[TEntity]):

    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    def add(self, entity: TEntity):
        self.session.add(entity)

    def remove(self, entity: TEntity):
        pass

    def get_by_id(self, id_: uuid.UUID) -> TEntity:
        return self.session.query(self._entity_type).get(id_)

    def persist(self, entity: TEntity):
        pass

    def persist_all(self):
        pass

    def collect_events(self):
        pass
import uuid
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

from .id_generator import GenericUUID
from ..entities.entity_base import BaseEntity

TEntity = TypeVar('TEntity', bound=BaseEntity)


class AbstractRepository(Generic[TEntity], ABC):
    """An interface for a generic repository"""

    _entity_type: object

    @abstractmethod
    def add(self, entity: TEntity):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def remove(self, entity: TEntity):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def get_by_id(self, id_: uuid.UUID) -> TEntity:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def persist(self, entity: TEntity):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def persist_all(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def collect_events(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def __getitem__(self, index) -> TEntity:
        return self.get_by_id(index)

    @staticmethod
    def next_id() -> uuid.UUID:
        return GenericUUID.next_id()
```

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71720366/8091093) answer helpful.