# How to use different module in the parent class depending on the child?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I am trying to have a parent class which will do the same thing for 2 child databases (Hana and Oracle in my example).

I would like to properly type the parent class.

The example I would like is as follows. It works at runtime, but typing gets crazy for multiple reasons:

- Module cannot be used as a type
- `T.Connection` is not valid syntax

```py
from typing import Type, cast, get_args

import oracledb  # want to use oracledb.Connection
from hdbcli import dbapi  # want to use dbapi.Connection


class Parent[T: oracledb | dbapi]:
    _db_type: Type[T]

    def __init_subclass__(cls) -> None:
        # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71720366/2473382 to get T at runtime
        cls._db_type = cast(Type[T], get_args(cls.__orig_bases__[0])[0])

    def conn(self, **kwargs) -> T.Connection:
        return self._db_type.Connection(**kwargs)


class Hana(Parent[dbapi]): ...
class Oracle(Parent[oracledb]): ...
```

I could give `Connection` as parameter of `super().__init__`, for instance:

```py
class Parent[T: dbapi.Connection]:
    _conn: Type[T]

    def __init__(self, conn: Type[T]):
        self._conn = conn

    def conn(self, **kwargs) -> T:
        return self._conn(**kwargs)


class Hana(Parent[dbapi.Connection]):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(dbapi.Connection)
```

But then if I need more than one object (Connection, Cursor...) I need to duplicate the parameters and generics.

What would be a clean way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using an abstract class in the design? I might be missing something, I've also never used the class name[ syntax.

Comment: @TimothyH The parent will be an abstract class, with some implemented methods, indeed. It wrote here the smallest possible code where my issue shows.

Comment: @OysterShucker on one hand, you are correct. On the other one, getting proper typing helps a lot to catch potential bugs early, and usually if typing is not happy, it means that something dirty is happening. It is not bad per se, but good to be aware of it.

Comment: @Guillaume - I disagree. You have 2 choices - spin your wheels trying to invent a type that your editor accepts or learn how to read tracebacks. You are really just doing all of this work so you can catch the error before you run the program. You could just run the program, get the error, understand it, and fix it. I'm not against strict-typing. I love strict-typing ... in languages that actually require it. Why use python at all if you are determined to treat it like it's Java, C or some other heavily involved language? Python is supposed to be super easy and forgiving.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to work with a regular class inheritance, but this gets everything correctly type-checked and enforced during static type checking, with correct types available to mypy.

It also makes it so that you don't have to pass the type via `__init__`. It does, however, mean that you still have to enumerate all the parts of the module that you're using. The only way I can find that might not require that would involve breaking typechecking compatibility with Python and using `basedmypy` instead of `mypy`.

I used "Path" as a stand-in for "Connection" and "pathlib"/"zipfile" as stand-ins for oracledb and dbapi.

```
from typing import Type, Protocol, TypeVar, TYPE_CHECKING
import pathlib
import zipfile
import typing

PathType = TypeVar("PathType", bound=Type[object]) # Represents "Connection". Create a new TypeVar for each class that you're using in the modules.

class ModuleProtocol(Protocol[PathType]):
    Path: PathType

def create_subclass(module_type: ModuleProtocol[PathType]) -> Type[ModuleProtocol[PathType]]:
    class DbProtocol(ModuleProtocol[PathType]):
        Path=module_type.Path
        
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        _: type[ModuleProtocol[PathType]] = DbProtocol # If Path is not set, this correctly errors that DbProtocol hasn't set Path correctly from module_type
    return DbProtocol


PathLibBased = create_subclass(pathlib)
ZipFileBased = create_subclass(zipfile)
# PathLibBased = create_subclass(typing) # Error (arg-type). Correctly detects that "typing" module does not have "Path".

# reveal_type(PathLibBased.Path) # Reveals pathlib.Path type correctly.
# reveal_type(ZipFileBased.Path) # Reveals zipfile.Path type correctly.
```