# Get TypeVars of custom Generic Class from instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, typing, type-variables

I have something like this:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Tuple

T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')
U = TypeVar('U')

class Foo(Generic[T, S]):
    def get_type_vars(self) -> Tuple[TypeVar]:
        return  #TODO how do I return T and S here?

assert Foo().get_type_vars() == (T, S)
```

Is there any way to get this behavior? I need a way to find out, that `S` and `T` are the TypeVars of the generic Class `Foo`. Any ideas?

I should mention that I write some class decorators and the method `get_type_vars()` will be added to the class by a decorator. So all I have is the instance `self` in the method:

```
def get_type_vars(self) -> Tuple[TypeVar]:
        return  #TODO how do I return T and S here in case that self is an instance of Foo?
```

Comment: Oh right. I should mention that I write some class decorators and the method `get_type_vars()` will be added to the class be a decorator. So all I have is the instance `self`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the type arguments of typing.Generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572831/how-to-access-the-type-arguments-of-typing-generic)

Comment: @CorentinPane No, it does not. Because I only have an instance of the class. I'll update my question.

Comment: well you can always do `type(self)` to get the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_args` combined with `__orig_bases__` to inspect generic types of the base class:

```py
class Foo(Generic[T, S]):
    def get_type_vars(self) -> Tuple[TypeVar]:
        return get_args(type(self).__orig_bases__[0])
```

This would get a bit more complicated for more complex inheritance chains though.

Comment: Thank you, this looks nice. So I was very close with my attempts.