# Get generic type of class at runtime with Python 3.6

Tags: python, generics

Following a solution described in this question: [How to access the type arguments of typing.Generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572831/how-to-access-the-type-arguments-of-typing-generic)

I have successfully solved a generic type at runtime in Python 3.8. However I can't seem to be able to access the `__args__` field described in the solution for Python 3.6. I'm not sure why, here's my code:

```py
def get_generic_type_arg(cls):
    if py_version >= (3, 8):
        t = cls.__orig_bases__[0]
        return get_args(t)[0]
    else:
        t = cls.__args__
        return None

class EventContract:
    @classmethod
    def get_version(cls) -> int:
        return int(cls.__name__[1:])


RT = TypeVar('RT', bound=EventContract)


class QueryContract(Generic[RT], EventContract):
    """ Base class for query contracts that are versioned. """

    @classmethod  # Do not override this
    def get_response_class(cls) -> Type[RT]:
        return get_generic_type_arg(cls)

    def build_result(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_response_class()(**kwargs)


@dataclasses.dataclass
class V1Response(EventContract):
    value: int


@dataclasses.dataclass
class V1(QueryContract[V1Response]):
    id: int
    name: str
```

When trying to call `get_generic_type` on `cls` I get an `AttributeError`. I also tried to fetch its base class using `t.__bases__[0]` which gives me the `QueryContract` with no generic arguments (`__args__` gives me another attribute error). I am calling the `get_response_class` method on `V1`. Any ideas ?

Comment: I have realised that Python 3.6 doesn't support dataclasses anyways. Still interested in the solution with normal classes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to do it. For some reason, `__orig_bases__` wasn't working but after rebuilding my Python 3.6 and using a VENV, it works. This is the final working method:

```py
py_version = sys.version_info
if py_version >= (3, 8):
    from typing import get_args


def get_generic_type_arg(cls):
    t = cls.__orig_bases__[0]
    if py_version >= (3, 8):
        return get_args(t)[0]
    else:
        return t.__args__[0]
```

Python 3.6 also requires to install `dataclasses` as a library though it wasn't part of this issue. Also note that `__args__` seems to be undocumented in Python 3.6 and removed from Python 3.8.

Comment: Feels too low level, I'd rather pass my type as a regular variable if I needed this level of introspection and it [wasn't supported through a stable language facade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57706180/1509695)