# Python find type of value for typing.Dict

Tags: python, class, typing, python-dataclasses

If I have

```
class A:
    pass

def my_func(my_dict: typing.Dict[str, A]):
    pass
```

How can I find the **type** of the values in this dict? Basically, how can I figure out that the values that go into `my_dict` are supposed to be of type `A`?

To give some context I have two dataclasses

```
@dataclass
class B:
    x: str

@dataclass
class C:
    y: Dict[str, B]
```

I'm trying to look at `class C` and figure out which object I need to instantiate. In this example, I want to create object B.

```
class_type = C.__annotations__["y"]  # this returns typing.Dict[str, B]
# now need to create the object
b = class_type[1](x="bar")  # index 1 to retrieve the B class in typing.Dict[str, B]
c = C(y = {"foo": b})
```

I'm trying to create `b` but obviously index of 1 in a mutable map doesn't work.

Comment: This would be an unusual way to use annotations. Even if you successfully retrieve the `A` class, you have no idea what instances of that class represent, no idea where to find such instances, and no idea how to meaningfully construct one.

Comment: (You, the human, might understand class `A`, but annotation-processing code you write is going to be clueless.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572831/how-to-access-the-type-arguments-of-typing-generic) with `__annotations__[<key>]` and you will get what you need

```
print(typing.get_args(my_func.__annotations__['my_dict']))
# will return (<class 'str'>, <class '__main__.A'>)
```

Comment: OMG You're a beast