# accessing type variable in a static method

Tags: python

For a class that is created with a `TypeVar`, is there a way I can print the value of the `TypeVar` inside a static class method? For instance:

```
T = TypeVar("T")
class Foo(Generic[T]):
    @staticmethod
    def print():
        # what should I put here in order for the following code to print int?
        # there is no 'self' here so I can't do typing.get_args(self)

Foo[int].print()
```

Note: this is not the same as [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572831/how-to-access-the-type-arguments-of-typing-generic) that accesses the type arguments inside a variable. Here I am asking how to access the type arguments *inside a class static method* itself.

Comment: Even if it *was* a regular instance method, `typing.get_args(self)` wouldn't return `int`

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am writing a function that takes `Class` or `_GenericAlias` as arguments and printing their names in a custom way. So `print(int, bool, List[int])` should print `myint, mybool, and mylist_myint`