# Calling class method on generic type for class in Python

Tags: python, generics

Suppose I have an abstract base class, `Base` that is inherited by another class, `Derived`:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound = Foo)

class Base(Generic[T]):

    def do_thing(self):

        # This won't work
        result = T.class_method(...)

class Derived(Base[Bar]):

    def do_other_thing(self):

        result = self.do_thing()
```

The goal here is that when `do_other_thing` is called, `Bar.class_method` is called, returning result. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572831/how-to-access-the-type-arguments-of-typing-generic), I could accomplish this using `get_args( Derived.__orig_bases__[0] )[0].class_method()` but I don't see how I can do this without hardcoding the class type. How can I get this code to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood indeed.
In your example, the class in never instantiated with a type. Python can only know the correct class for T once the class has been instantiated. When it is instantiated you can assign a field to the correct class and use that to call the `class_method`:

```py
from typing import Generic, Type, TypeVar

class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        print('class method')

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Foo)

class Base(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, cls: Type[T]):
        self.cls = cls

    def do_thing(self):
        print(f'{self.cls=}')
        # This works
        result = self.cls.class_method()

class Derived(Base[Bar]):
    def do_other_thing(self):
        result = self.do_thing()

with_isntance = Derived(Bar())
with_isntance.do_other_thing()
with_class = Derived(Bar)
with_class.do_other_thing()
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question as I want to know what to do with the `T.class_method(...)` piece.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still testing this solution but it seems to work. I noticed that the `__orig_class__` property contains the original, generic type associated with the current object. So, all I did was add a new function, called `_get_t` that calls `typing.get_args` with this type information, thereby retrieving the type of the generic parameter, which I can then use:

```
def _get_t(self) -> Type[T]:
    return get_args(self.__orig_class__)[0]
```

I can then modify `do_thing` to use this:

```
def do_thing(self):

    result = self._get_t().class_method(...)
```