# set class attribute from passed generic type

Tags: python, generics

I have Base repository class with Generic class inherit to work with sqlalchemy models and get better type annotations. So, in my base class I have class attribute `model_class`. It passed to methods, so I don't need to specify model parameter in all methods.

Now I just check in `__init_subclass__` method, that child classes implement model_class attribute to avoid errors like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from app.core.models.tables import Base, SomeModel

BaseSQLAlchemyModel = TypeVar('BaseSQLAlchemyModel', bound=Base)


class BaseRepository(Generic[BaseSQLAlchemyModel]):
    model_class: type[BaseSQLAlchemyModel]

    def __init_subclass__(cls: type['BaseRepository[BaseSQLAlchemyModel]']) -> None:
        if not hasattr(cls, 'model_class'):
            msg = '...'
            raise SomeException(msg)

    def some_base_method(self: 'BaseRepository[BaseSQLAlchemyModel]', ...) -> BaseSQLAlchemyModel:
        return ...
  

class MyRepository(BaseRepository[SomeModel]):
    model_class = SomeModel
```

But I want to not set `model_class` every time and just get it from inherited generic passed type (SomeModel in this case). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What I understand is that you want model_class to be set based only in the [SomeModel] part?. It can't be done. In python, type checking and actual code are totally unrelated

Comment: @Joaquín but it is possible. I've just implemented it in my code. I'll write the solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

According to [c-z user solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50101934/19280804), I implemented the following code in my `__init_subclass__` methods:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, get_args
from app.core.models.tables import Base, SomeModel

BaseSQLAlchemyModel = TypeVar('BaseSQLAlchemyModel', bound=Base)


class BaseRepository(Generic[BaseSQLAlchemyModel]):
    model_class: type[BaseSQLAlchemyModel]

    def __init_subclass__(cls: type['BaseRepository[BaseSQLAlchemyModel]']) -> None:
        if not hasattr(cls, 'model_class'):
            try:
                # PEP-560
                type_ = get_args(cls.__orig_bases__[0])[0]  # type: ignore
                if not isinstance(type_, Base):
                    msg = '...'
                    raise SomeException(msg)
                cls.model_class = type_
            except Exception as exc:
                msg = '...'
                raise SomeException(msg) from exc

    def some_base_method(self: 'BaseRepository[BaseSQLAlchemyModel]', ...) -> BaseSQLAlchemyModel:
        return ...
  

class MyRepository(BaseRepository[SomeModel]):
    ...  # no model_class = ...
```

another `[0]` in `get_args` line is needed, because `__init_subclass__` receive subclass in `cls` parameter, so the result of `get_args` without `[0]` will be the tuple of classes.

It is, maybe, not a good solution, but it works for me and I still could get my `SomeException` error, if something will go wrong.

**update 1**: added check for isinstance of `type_` - passed generic type, because if no type were specified like class `class MyRepository(BaseRepository): pass`, `type_` will contains TypeVar, so for make sure, I check it in try-except block.